# Linux distribution for old laptop

Tags: distribution-choice

I want to install a new Linux distribution on my old [ThinkPad 600x laptop](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:600X):

- Pentium 3 500MHz processor
- 448MB RAM
- 4MB graphics memory
- around 20GB HDD
- CD-ROM drive
- WiFi card on PCMCIA

I want a fast, lightweight distribution. It only needs to run web browser (with flash support), nothing more. The distribution size doesn't matter, as long as it fits on a CD. A fast WM would be appreciated.

Currently, it runs Lubuntu 12.10, which I find too slow and unresponsive.

I was looking at Puppy (Wary 5.5) and it's my first candidate to install, but I was hoping for other suggestions.

Comment: I did a quick search and found this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42364/modern-distribution-on-old-hardware?rq=1

Comment: It's unlikely that anything else running X + LXDE will be any quicker than Lubuntu; the "slowness" is the actual apps you are actually using.  A standalone window manager  *may* make a bit of difference but switching distros will not.  The norm on the raspberry pi, which is only slightly beefier (700 Mhz, 512 MB RAM) is Debian w/ LXDE.  It is just a slow computer, period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest Puppy which you've already found or the following:

- Damn Small Linux: http://damnsmalllinux.org/
- Or roll your own: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/

The advantage of LFS is that it would be specifically tailored to your laptop so nothing installed that doesn't need to be and you would also learn a lot about Linux.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the focus on distributions geared at being *lightweight* is *passé*. Indeed, if you look at the [*Arch Linux*](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/beginners%27_guide#System_requirements) requirements for instance you will see that:

> Arch Linux should run on any i686 compatible machine with a minimum of
>   64 MB RAM. A basic installation with all packages from the base group
>   should take less than 800 MB of disk space. If you are working with
>   limited space, this can be trimmed down considerably, but you will
>   have to know what you are doing.

That's only an example and may not account for sophisticated graphical environments. An attractive preconfigured "light" spin is [*ArchBang*](http://wiki.archbang.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)... with the *Openbox* window manager. You can do *minimal installs* with many distributions. Qualifying a distribution as being *light* is just a matter of default install options mostly; you can scale the window managers and desktop environments the way you want and layer the extra components to suit your requirements.